# Using one parameter on multiple formulas in Crystal reports. Resulting possible corruption

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

Please bear with me on this one, this might not be a clear question. I am having a serious problem, I can present the problem, I can retrace the steps leading to it but do not know how to fix it. It is well possible, that my report (or even system) is corrupted in some way now, as editing the changes back does (to a point where everything worked) produce the same problem. **I am looking for some ideas on how to fix the report in this possible corrupt state**, as redoing from the start would take very much time. I use the latest Crystal Reports.

Retracing the steps:

I have a complex report, that takes a parameter, `ID1`. This `ID1` is used in a select expert statement. All is fine at this point.

I had need of this `ID1` in an SQL command data source. I could not write this parameter into the SQL command. (Crystal would not let me.) Oh well, I create parameter `ID2`, that is the same. Now everything is fine, although I have to supply my parameter twice.

Now I find all references of `ID1` and replace them with `ID2`. When nothing uses `ID1` I delete that parameter. So I wanted to have only one parameter. Now the report starts to act strange. Wen running it does not pass my parameter to the SQL command, nor the select expert formula. Debugging in the DBMS I see that the ID in the SQL command is 0 (insted of 145768 for example) and the report's select command lacks the WHERE clasue, where the filter on ID should be. This is really bad, as I have to kill the operation, the DB is too big to handle at once.

Sadly editing back these last changes manually (so both `ID1` and `ID2` are in the report again) does not solve the problem. Even if I supply the parameter twice now, it still does not appear in the requests to the DBMS.

What can I do in this situation, besides starting the whole report over? Is there a way to check/fix the integrity of a report?

Sziro

Comment: To Ryan, Siva:
I have several tables as data source, linked together and whatnot and I have one command as data source. I have to use both.

Comment: Using both SQL Commands and also manually adding tables/joins is usually an over-complicated way to approach a report and will sometimes cause CR to behave differently than expected. If you absolutely must use two data sources then review your SQL Command and verify the parameter is set up and referenced correctly.

Comment: FYI, either comment below the actual answer you want to respond to or use the '@Sziro' convention to notify another comment/answer author... otherwise we won't see your response.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. As of now the command is a must. Putting everything to a command is quite ugly and unmaintainable on the long run. I will recreate the report, and try to maintain backups frequently, as time presses me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be using a selection formula when your report is based off of a SQL Command. The point of a SQL command is that you can manually specify the query, including the WHERE-clause, without having to rely on Crystal to form the query for you. You're not seeing the query you expect hitting the database because Crystal can't reconcile the two different sets of logic simultaneously.

My suggestion is to do away with the selection formula completely and move all of its logic into the SQL Command itself. Just as a reminder, you need to create parameters within' the SQL Command window itself... a parameter created "the normal way" will not work. If you do this correctly the query you see being run on the database will be exactly the query that appears in your SQL Command.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a SQL command not using tables then you need to write the parameter at the SQL query level itself as that is the query that is getting fired in database. Try to create parameter at the `command` and see your report works fine or not